# getting time remaing from file upload with php

Tags: php, jquery

i want to upload a file in a way that user can see how many time is remaining from upload...with php and jquery $.ajax();

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't alter your server environment, use one of the Flash based uploading solutions like [SWFUpload](http://www.swfupload.org) or [Uploadify](http://www.uploadify.com). (It's not possible to transmit files using pure Ajax as far as I know).

SWFUpload has a [speed plugin](http://demo.swfupload.org/v220/speeddemo/index.php) that does exactly what you want, out of the box.

Comment: No one uses uploadify anymore

Answer (score 3):

You may want to look into http://t.wits.sg/2008/06/25/howto-php-and-jquery-upload-progress-bar/

Answer (score 1):

This might be what you are looking for http://www.uploadify.com/

if not some more information would be helpful, are you using http or ftp upload for starters.